# Is it possible to have child DIVs scale alongside parent? Need some serious advice

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scaling

I've been trying to accomplish [this design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPX3D.jpg) the whole day. 
I need all the content on screen to scale down proportionally to a certain point where I can fix the rest up with media queries.
I can get the main content box to scale down with background-size:contain;
But whenever I try to get the content inside the box to scale down it either shrinks a lot quicker, becomes off-centered or just shoots out of the box when you scale the browser window.
I've been googling like nuts, trying all sorts things - I just tried flexbox but it just ends up with the same result.

There's no need for me to provide my codes because I'm at square one regardless. Is there any way to accomplish this?
I'm at a pretty beginner level when it comes to coding.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still, come up with your "best shot" at the issue, and show us a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example, with a fiddle or snippet if possible, detailing exactly what you are expecting and what you get. There are many ways of handling different sizes for the design you posted, it's difficult to guess exactly what you want. You'll have to provide at least two sizes, or give a very specific and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

lots of ways to skin the cat on this one. For instance, when you say scale, are you referring to responsive designs? If so, then you would either have to make your own, or use a popular one like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), or [semantic ui](https://semantic-ui.com/), or something along those lines.

If you are simply asking about scaling down, then that is simply accomplished by using flexible CSS measurments such as percents, em, rem, and the like.

Specific code examples are too numerous to post a representative sample.

But in general so long as you don't set fixed widths, then they should scale in the manner I mentioned